# Flatten Synchronous Angular Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

How can I run a series of promises synchronously such that the second promise is not executed until the first one is done?  Here I'm loading three chunks of data, each 10 clients long, then loading the rest.  The idea here is that go ahead and display the first N clients while the rest are loading.

What I don't want is to have to explicitly say processChunk1().then(() => processChunk2()) etc. like I have below.  I want it to process the chunks in a loop until there are no more clients left.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
loadPerformanceDtos(): ng.IPromise<{}> {
    var deferred = this.$q.defer();
    var clientList: any = [];

    $.extend(clientList, this.$location.search().client);

    // If the user only searched for one client, we need to turn it into an array
    if (!angular.isArray(clientList)) {
        clientList = [clientList];
    }

    var that = this;

    // Sort so we can chunk it
    var sortedClients: string[] = (<string[]>clientList).sort();
    const chunkSize: number = 10;

    // Reset page's data
    this.performanceDtoModels = [];

    // Set up three chunks to load in order
    var chunk1: string[] = sortedClients.splice(0, chunkSize);
    var chunk2: string[] = sortedClients.splice(0, chunkSize);
    var chunk3: string[] = sortedClients.splice(0, chunkSize);

    // I don't want to have to explicitly define the groups below, I want this to be in a loop
    processChunk(chunk1).then(() => {
        // Resolve the inital page's progress bar
        deferred.resolve();

        processChunk(chunk2).then(() => {
            processChunk(chunk3).then(() => {
                processChunk(sortedClients);
            });
        });
    });

    function processChunk(chunk: string[]) {
        var chunkDeferred = that.$q.defer();
        if (chunk.length === 0) {
            chunkDeferred.resolve();
        } else {
            that.performanceService.loadPerformanceData(chunk)
                .success((data: IPerformanceDtoModel[]) => {
                    data.forEach((item: IPerformanceDtoModel) => {
                        // Add the final item to the page
                        that.performanceDtoModels.push(item);
                    });

                    chunkDeferred.resolve();
                });
        }
        return chunkDeferred.promise;
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a recursive function that calls itself with a slice of the original list after each async operation completes. Below is a sample implementation. Note that `processChunks` calls itself after each async operation.

This implementation does not account for when the async method fails. It does not include any way to know when all chunks have finished loading. For the latter, you'd have to add some logic to determine when the last chunk is done loading.

```
class YourClass {

    loadPerformanceDtos(): ng.IPromise<{}> {
        this.loadDeferred = this.$q.defer();

        var requestedClients: string|string[] = this.$location.search().client;

        var clientList: string[];
        if (!angular.isArray(requestedClients)) {
            clientList = [requestedClients];
        } else {
            clientList = requestedClients;
        }

        clientList.sort();
        this.performanceDtoModels = [];
        this.processChunks(clientList, 10);
    }

    processChunks(list: string[], size: number) {
        var chunk = list.slice(0, size);

        // Resolve the initial page's progress bar
        if (this.performanceDtoModels.length > 0) {
            this.loadDeferred.resolve();
        }

        if (chunk.length > 0) {
            this.processChunk(chunk).then(() => {
                this.processChunks(list.slice(size), size);
            });
        }

    }

    processChunk(chunk: string[]) {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();

        if (chunk.length === 0) {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        else {
            this.performanceService.loadPerformanceData(chunk)
                .success((data: IPerformanceDtoModel[]) => {
                    data.forEach((item) => {
                        this.performanceDtoModels.push(item);
                    });

                deferred.resolve();
            });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  I intentionally left out error handling for brevity and can handle that myself.  I just needed some direction to make it generic since all of the resources I found expect that you have a known number of promise chains.